# Browser successfully received the given MVC Web API response - How to ensure in server side?

Tags: api, events, model-view-controller, response, action-filter

I am writing a web API for GET method. This method will return JSON object as  response. I need an action filter method or an event that invokes automatically when the browser successfully received the response.

Comment: Do you need this event on the server or on the client (i.e. browser)? If on the server, define "successfully received".

Comment: I need it in server side. not in client side.

Comment: Then define "successfully received". How is the server to determine what that means? As @bwyn suggested, one option is to let the client decide what success means, and have them notify the server with an additional call.

Comment: Kirsh, I will make it clear. i need to store the response data in a database table when the client is successfully received the response. If this can be determined by client then client has to call another one API method saying the client is successfully received the response. On this, i need to previous re-produce response data once again in server side else, i need to keep it in session or somewhere else.

instead of doing all these things, can i get a event or action filter in server side when the client is successfully received response?

Comment: You seem to be missing the point. It is easy for the server to know that is has sent a message to the client. What is impossible for the server to know, is whether the client "received it successfully", whatever that means, unless the client tells the server. So again: please define "received successfully".

Answer (score 0):

The following has been adapted from Professional JavaScript for Web Developers (3rd Edition) by Nicholas Zakas:

**Ajax Function:**

```
function Ajax() {
    var xhr, responseObj, getCompletionFunction;
    var completionFunction;

    this.setGetCompletionFunction = function (value) { getCompletionFunction = value; }

    this.getRequest = function (url) {
        completionFunction = getCompletionFunction;
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onreadystatechange = readyStateChangeFunction;
        xhr.open("get", url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.send(null);
    }

    function readyStateChangeFunction() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300 || xhr.status == 304) {
                responseObj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                completionFunction(responseObj);
            } else {
                var errorMessage = xhr.status;
                responseObj = { errorMessages: ["An error of type " + errorMessage + " occurred while attempting to reach the server."] };
                completionFunction(responseObj);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line of interest is:

```
if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300 || xhr.status == 304) {
```

This determines whether the Web Api call was successful. If so, the function parses the response and inputs it to the callback. Otherwise, an error message is returned to the callback.

**Example of using the Ajax Function:**

```
var ajax = new Ajax();

var completionFunction = function (data) {
    var returnedData = data;
}

ajax.setGetCompletionFunction(completionFunction);

ajax.getRequest("/api/Home/1");
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But any possibilities to get that in server side?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to send an additional ajax call to the server from the callback